# Spring way to set Content-Type when using a Writer

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Normally, I try to avoid using `HttpServletResponse` in my Spring Web MVC controllers. In one controller, I have code that is writing to a `Writer` object instead of returning a response. I'd like to have the controller also set the `Content-Type` to `text/csv`.

First, the controller does declare a `produces`, but that does not set any Content-Type.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "export.csv", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/csv")
public void export(Writer writer) {
...
}
```

I tried returning a `ResponseEntity<Void>` and set the Content-Type there. However, that threw an exception stating that the Writer object has already been obtained.

Finally, it can of course work using an `HttpServletResponse`, but I suspect there must be a way to do it without using servlet APIs directly.

The project uses Spring Boot 1.2.7. (This includes Spring Framework 4.1.8, I believe).

Comment: Why avoid using HttpServletResponse?  It's handy enough.

Comment: Mostly because `HttpServletResponse` is a fairly low-level API, and the Spring classes provide nicer abstractions, like `MediaType` and `HttpHeader`. This example might not yield much benefit from using the Spring APIs, but in other controllers I've greatly appreciated them.

Comment: You must use a `HttpServletResponse` in order to do this.